# Logstash Grok Parse Error - fail2ban log

Tags: logstash-grok, grok, fail2ban

I am trying to parse a `fail2ban` log file using the config file and pattern below (via an online tutorial).

However I am getting a grok parse error, any ideas how to fix this?

**log file format:**

```
2017-02-13 18:49:52,567 fail2ban.actions    [1365]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 127.0.0.1
```

**logstash config:**

```
input {
  file {
    type => "fail2ban"
    start_position => "beginning"
    path => [ "/var/log/fail2ban.log" ]
  }
}

filter {
  if [type] == "fail2ban" {
    grok {
      patterns_dir => "/etc/logstash/patterns"
      match => [
        "message", "%{F2B_DATE:date} %{F2B_ACTION} %{WORD:level} %{F2B_JAIL} %{WORD:action} %{IP:ip}",
        "message", "%{F2B_DATE:date} %{F2B_ACTION} %{F2B_LEVEL} %{GREEDYDATA:msg}?"
      ]
    }

    geoip {
      source => "ip"
    }
  }
}
```

**pattern config:**

```
F2B_DATE %{YEAR}-%{MONTHNUM}-%{MONTHDAY}[ ]%{HOUR}:?%{MINUTE}(?::?%{SECOND})
F2B_ACTION (\w+)\.(?:\w+)(\s+)?\:
F2B_JAIL \[(?<jail>\w+\-?\w+?)\]
F2B_LEVEL (?<level>\w+)\s+
```

Comment: if you could show the `grok parse` error?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing out the *carrot* `^` symbol in your **match**, which means to say to the pattern that this is where to *start* with, in the log line. What if you have your **match** as such:

```
match => [
     "message", "^%{F2B_DATE:date} %{F2B_ACTION} %{WORD:level} %{F2B_JAIL} %{WORD:action} %{IP:ip}",
     "message", "^%{F2B_DATE:date} %{F2B_ACTION} %{F2B_LEVEL} %{GREEDYDATA:msg}?"
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but that didn't change a thing.

Answer (score 0):

The F2B_ACTION pattern is failing.
Using the example you supplied:

```
2017-02-13 18:49:52,567 fail2ban.actions    [1365]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 127.0.0.1
```

And using this Grok pattern:

```
%{F2B_DATE:date} %{GREEDYDATA:failtoban.actions} %{F2B_LEVEL} %{F2B_JAIL} %{WORD:action} %{IP:ip}
```

I got this result:

```
{
  "date": [
    "2017-02-13 18:49:52,567"
  ],
  "failtoban": [
    "fail2ban.actions    [1365]:"
  ],
  "level": [
    "NOTICE"
  ],
  "jail": [
    "sshd"
  ],
  "action": [
    "Ban"
  ],
  "ip": [
    "127.0.0.1"
  ]
}
```

I used *%{GREEDYDATA:failtoban.actions}* because I am not sure of which values can be valid, but like is the problem is solved.